# Reading binary file hanging using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to

1. Save a numpy n-dimensional array to a *.bin file as a string of bits.
2. Read said *.bin file using `tf.FixedLengthRecordReader`
3. Extract information using `tf.decode_raw`

This is a fairly standard operation, perfomed countless times, with countless examples online. I have tried copying line for line the example done in the tensorflow example mode. ([Found here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py))

Below you see my attempt. The moment I try to evaluate `record_bytes`, the entire process hangs. I have rewritten the code multiple times, so I am not sure where I am messing up.

In terms of trying to debug it. I am sure that the binary file is being made properly, as I can properly open and read the contents of the file using the python method `open()`

Not sure how to debug the tensorflow part of the code.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from array import array

import tensorflow as tf

# Generate File
array = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 3], [4, 5, 6, 6]], [[10, 20, 30, 30], [40, 50, 60, 60]],[[2, 4, 8, 8],[16, 32, 64, 64]]])
output_file = open('temp_file.bin', 'wb')
array.astype('uint8').tofile(output_file)
print(array.shape)
output_file.close()

# Attempt to read file
with tf.Session():
    num_bytes = 3*2*4
    reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=num_bytes)
    filenames = ['temp_file.bin']
    for f in filenames:
        if not tf.gfile.Exists(f):
            raise ValueError('Failed to find file: ' + f)
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)
    print(record_bytes.eval())
```

Comment: Describe the problem better.

Comment: I have attempted to clarify what I am doing. As for what the problem is, I am not sure, as the process hangs with no indication for the cause of the issue.

Comment: No stack trace?

Comment: The process hangs, not fails, so a stacktrace isn't immediately available. Not certain which point of the code hangs.